# Use IntegrityError exception (in Django) to check if username is taken?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I wanted to create a signup form in Django and throw an error if the username already exists. I have seen people have used User.DoesNotExist() method to check that, but can you use IntegrityError exception as follows for that purpose? I have read the definition of IntegrityError but honestly do not quite understand this: This exception is raised when the relational integrity of the data is affected.

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': UserCreationForm})
    else:
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            try:
                user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                user.save()
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            except IntegrityError:
                return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': UserCreationForm, 'error': 'Username already exists'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': UserCreationForm, 'error': 'Passwords do not match'})
```

I have seen this code in a Django project. I would appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

IntegrityError is raised when the DB refuses to store data because it violates a constraint. In this case, probably a unique constraint on the username. So this code should be OK.

Checking to see if `User.objects.filter(username=...).exists()` is potentially vulnerable to a race condition where another process/thread creates the same username after you check but before you can save your new object. Not likely, not catastrophic in this case, but catching IntegrityError is better if you are certain it will be raised

Personally I would use

```
user, created = User.objects.get_or_create( 
     username = request.POST['username'], 
     initial={ 'password': request.POST['password1']} 
)
if created:
    # everything OK
else:
    # user already existed, so report an error
```

This is safe against races and also works even in a case where no DB constraint would be violated by creating a duplicate object.